# Cannot Add Registered Servers in SSMS 2008R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

When I go to the Registered Servers toolbar to add some registered servers under Database Engine, there is no option for Local group. The window is completely empty. When I try to right click in the window I don't get any options either. Is there something else that I need to enable in order to utilize this feature?

Comment: Can you show a screen shot and explain where you are trying to "right click in the window"?

Comment: Here is a screenshot - [link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/801/dy1m.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd one - I'd suggested running a repair on your management tools, or using a more modern version. [SQL Server 2012 SP1 does not need to be licensed](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579) and you will still be able to use it to manage all of your 2005, 2008 and 2008 R2 instances.